# Creating trees of indeterminate depth with knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I am using knockout to create a simple blogging system with comments.  Comment trees can be an indeterminate number of levels deep but I am not sure how to do this with knockout.  Here is the object structure:

```
var BlogEntry = function(entry) {
    var self = this;

    self.author = ko.observable(entry.Author);
    self.submitted = ko.observable(entry.Submitted);
    self.comments = ko.observableArray();        
    for(var commentIndex in entry.Comments) {
        self.comments.push(new BlogComment(entry[commentIndex]));
    }
}

var BlogComment = function(comment) {
    var self = this;

    self.author = ko.observable(comment.Author);
    self.submitted = ko.observable(comment.Submitted);
    self.comments = ko.observableArray();
    for(var subCommentIndex in comment.Comments) {
        self.comments.push(new BlogComment(comment[subCommentIndex]));
    }
}
```

I want something like this:

```
<div id="BlogEntries" data-bind="foreach: comments">
    <div class="blog-entry">
        <div data-bind="text: author() + " - " + submitted()"></div>
        <div data-bind="foreach: comments">
            <div class="comment">
                <div data-bind="text: author() + " - " + submitted()"></div>
                <div data-bind="foreach: comments">
                    <!-- Would need infinite markup here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do this without setting an arbitrary max comment tree depth and writing out every possible level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. [Templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) can be used recursively. Try something like this.

```html
<script type="text/html" id="comment">
    <div class="comment">
        <!-- more comment specific stuff here -->
        <div data-bind="text: author() + ' - ' + submitted()"></div>
        <div class="comments" data-bind="template: {name: 'comment', foreach: comments}"></div>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="BlogEntries" data-bind="foreach: blogEntries">
    <div class="blog-entry">
        <!-- more blog-entry specific stuff here -->
        <div data-bind="text: author() + ' - ' + submitted()"></div>
        <div class="comments" data-bind="template: {name: 'comment', foreach: comments}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hint: Try to avoid calculations (like `author() + ' - ' + submitted()`) in the view; this binds your view more tightly to the structure of your view model than necessary. And it adds visual clutter.

Better: Either create a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) that returns a combined value or distribute the data over separate elements and arrange them appropriately.

http://jsfiddle.net/3ne16rex/

Comment: Thanks!  the actual code has a computed property for the title line, but I didn't want to clutter the example more than it already was.